# Array out of bounds at 0 in Sudoku program

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

I am a beginner in programming.In my brute force sudoku solver program in Java, i keep getting an array out of bound exception in line 34 for index 0! How can 0 be out of bounds? Please check the code and tell me if you find where the flaw is.
Thanks

```
import java.io.*;
class brute_sudoku
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter the elements of the sudoku using 0 for blanks");
int m[][] = new int[9][9];
for(int r = 0; r < 9; r ++)
{
System.out.println("Enter row " + (r + 1));
String row = in.readLine();
for(int c = 0; c < 9; c ++)
m[r][c]= row.charAt(c);
}
int blanks = 0;
for(int r = 0; r < 9; r ++)
for(int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
if(m[r][c] == 0)
blanks ++;
int n[] = new int[blanks];
blanks = 0;
for(int r = 0; r < 9; r ++)
for(int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
if(m[r][c] == 0)
{
n[blanks] = r*10 +c;
blanks ++;
}
int i = blanks;
while(true) 
{
if(m[n[i]/10][n[i]%10] == 9)
{
m[n[i]/10][n[i]%10] = 1;
i --;
continue;
}
else
{
m[n[i]/10][n[i]%10] ++;
boolean solved = true;
int count = 0;
for(int r = 0; r < 9; r ++)
{
count = 0;
for(int c = 0; c < 9; c ++)
count = count + m[r][c];
if(count != 45)
solved = false;
}
for(int c = 0; c < 9; c ++)
{
count = 0;
for(int r = 0; r < 9; r ++)
count = count + m[r][c];
if(count != 45)
solved = false;
}
for(int r = 2; r < 9; r  = r + 3)
for(int c = 2; c < 9; c = c + 3)
{
count = 0;
for(int r1 = r -2; r1 <=r; r1 ++)
for(int c1  = c -2; c1 <= c; c1 ++)
count = count = m[r1][c1];
if(count != 45)
solved = false;
}
if(solved)
break;
else
{
i = blanks;
continue;
}
}
}
System.out.println("Solved sudoku is:");
for(int r =0; r < 9; r ++)
{
for(int c = 0; c < 9; c ++)
System.out.print(m[r][c]);
System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where is line 34 in your above code?

Comment: Indenting is your friend

Comment: .Post the actual stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

The line above line 34 `if(m[n[i]/10][n[i]%10] == 9)` can surely cause a **Array Out Of Bounds** exception because:

The statement `n[i] % 10`, it could return anything from 0 - 9. If it returns 9, it is disaster!